# Node Js: how to execute functions async in the start of the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, middleware

I want to run a function from an exported file as the first function in the application (async way).

this function must be executed the first when running the server and will ask us if it's a local or production environnement !

the function is in config file:

```
//config/config.js:

const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
module.exports= function(next) {
    console.log("call fi,n");
    rl.question('Run in production environnement (Y|N) ?', (answer) => {
        if(answer === "Y")
            process.env.NODE_ENV = 'prod';
        else
            process.env.NODE_ENV = 'dev';
        rl.close();
        console.log("asnwerere");
        next();
    },next);

}


//app.js:
app.use(function(next){
    require('./config/config')(next);
});
```

The first problem now that the function is not running in the start of the server But when receiving an HTTP request.

So the question how to make this function running in async way : as the first function of the application (must block the server until I introduce the command line mentioned in this function) ?

Comment: Show us your ```next``` variable declaration.

Comment: Your error shows `require('./config/config')(next);`, but the code you're showing us is `require('./config/database')(next);`.  Those two are different. 
 Are you 100% sure you're looking at the right code for the error?  What you show us should work and should not cause that error.  I think you're looking at the wrong line of code and the error is in a different place.

Comment: I thank you for your collaboration,

Yes you are right i was looking for the wrong code and I have recrified in the question but my problem now that I want my function async in the start of the server But my function now is running when receiving an HTTP request.

Comment: In the future, when addressing a comment directly to me, put @username at the front of the comment so I get notified about it.  Otherwise, I never know you posted a comment for me to see.

Comment: `app.use()` defines middleware.  Middleware runs during request processing, not at the start of your server.  That's what it does.  If you want something to run when your server starts, then don't put the code in middleware.  Put it in the code that runs when your server starts, such as the same place that you put `app.listen()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 : That's what I was seraching for, thank you! It rest the second thing, I want that an instruction will run async before app.listen. how I proceed ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This function signature

```
app.use(function(next){...});
```

is wrong.  It should be:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){...});
```

So, because you had the function arguments wrong, you were using the wrong thing as `next` and would get an error when someone tried to call it.

So, in your code change this:

```
//app.js:
app.use(function(next){
    require('./config/config')(next);
});
```

to this:

```
//app.js:
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    require('./config/config')(next);
});
```